# Placing same image at different places in QT

Tags: qt

I want to display the same image at different position. Image should display at all the position. I am using Qpixmap for placing image. Can any one suggest how to do it?.

Comment: I think you hsould create a new QPixmap with your image then create multiple object inheriting of QWidget. Then you overload the paintEvent() to add QPainter::drawPixmap() into it.

Comment: Different places on *what*? A `QWidget`? A QT Quick `Window`? Please be specific where the image should be placed, what's the source of the position, how should the image appear (as a stand-alone window, as a sub-widget, as a QML `Item`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QLabel` for this:

```
QList<QPoint> points = QList<QPoint>()
    << QPoint(0, 0)
    << QPoint(100, 100)
    << QPoint(200, 200);

QPixmap pixmap;
for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i)
{
    QLabel* label = new QLabel;
    label->setPixmap(pixmap);
    label->setGeometry(QRect(points[i], pixmap.size()));
    label->show();
}
```